# How to fix 'Impossible de résoudre la dépendance' error in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

Hi i am traying to use the webview controls in visual studio 2015 
after installing

```
"Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls"
```

it aske me to install

```
"Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView"
```

when i lunch the installation from NuGet packet manager i get this error

```
Gravité Code Description Projet Fichier Ligne État de la suppression Erreur 
Impossible de résoudre la dépendance « Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts ». 
Source(s) utilisée(s) : 'nuget.org', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline 
Packages'.0
```

sorry i am using a french version of Visual Vtudio

Comment: It will be better if you translate your errors before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Google translates your French error code flawlessly:

> Unable to resolve dependency "Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts"
>   Source(s) used: 'nuget.org', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'

I think you need the Windows SDK, which is not released via NuGet. You can download the applicable Windows SDK [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive)

Comment: Thanx Henri it work like charme sorry for the delay and i Will tray to trunslate my error in the next time ( this was my first time asking)